# Custom monoid with WriterT

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, monoids

I am trying to implement WriterT with custom data type. I have implemented the monoid as the required by runWriterT. But I am unable to compile the code. I get an error

*Could not deduce (Semigroup (Env a))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: Num a*

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Data.Monoid

newtype Env a = Env { getEnv :: a  }  deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)


instance Num a => Monoid (Env a) where
  mempty = Env 0
  Env x  `mappend` Env y = Env (x + y)


writeSomething :: (Num a) => WriterT (Env a) IO ()
writeSomething = do
  tell $ Env 1
  tell $ Env 3
```

Comment: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10365

Comment: `Env` just looks like Data.Monoid.Sum.

Comment: Yes it is. But I wanted to write a custom monoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In recent GHCs, `Semigroup` is a superclass of `Monoid`, so to create an instance of `Monoid` correctly, you must also create an instance of `Semigroup`. Luckily it's generally quite short:

```
instance Num a => Semigroup (Env a) where (<>) = mappend
```

Comment: Yes, but better is to define `Env x  <> Env y = Env (x + y)` and never talk about `mappend` ([“This method is redundant and has the default implementation `mappend = '(<>)'` since base-4.11.0.0”](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mappend)).